# Python error 'object string has no function'

Tags: python, cmd

As a relatively new programmer, I decided to make a small text adventure as my first project. It works fine, except when you try to go north. I am getting the error posting above. I believe it has to do with the variable location, but I'm not sure.

```
import random
import os
import time
os.system('cls')
yes = ("Yes", "yes", "y", "Y", "Yeah", "yeah", "yea", "Yea", "m8")
no = ("No", "no", "n", "N", "naw", "Naw", "Nope", "nope")
inventory = ("inv", "inventory", "i", "inven", "Inventory")
eats = ("eat","e", "Eat")
statss = ("stats", "s", "statistics", "Stats")
attack = ("attack", "combat", "a", "c", "fight", "Attack", "Combat", "Fight")
use = ("use", "u", "Use")
northh = ("Go North", "go north", "north", "North", "N", "n")
food = ("Bread")
items = ("Lantern")
weapons = ("Dagger")
hunger = 0
gold = 0
hp = 0 
inv = []
class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, desc, items, north):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.items = items
        self.north = north
CaveEntrance = Room("CaveEntrance", "The entrance to a large cave.", "Lantern", "None")
Beach = Room("Beach", "The beach. The sand is warm and the water is inviting.", "Lantern", "CaveEntrance")
inv.append ("Bread")
print("Hello, adventurer. What is your name?")
name = input("> ") 
print("Hello,",name,".",)
print("You have just begun a grand adventure. Prepare yourself now.")
def gen():
    global hp
    global gold      
    global hunger
    hp = random.randint(10, 25)
    gold = random.randint(0, 200)
    hunger = random.randint(10, 50)
    print("You start your journey with", hp, "hit points and", gold, "gold. You also have",hunger,"food.")
    print("Is this correct?")
    print("Y/N")
    ans = input("> ")
    if ans in yes:
        print("We will now continue") 
    if ans in no:
        print("Let's try again.")   
        gen()
gen()
print("STORY:")
print("You are going on vacation to the beach with your parents. You play in the waves for some time before noticing something off in the distance. Your curiosity is piqued. ")
location = Beach
def eat():
    global hunger
    print(*inv,sep='\n')
    print("Eat which item?")
    eatitem = input("> ")
    if eatitem in food and eatitem in inv:
        hunger = hunger + 5
        inv.remove(eatitem)
        print("Yum.")
        cmd()     
    elif eatitem not in inv:
        print("You don't have",eatitem,".")
        cmd()
    elif eatitem not in food:
        print("You can't eat that!")
        cmd()
def north():
    global location
    print("Heading north towards", location.north,"...") 
    time.sleep(2)
    location = location.north
    cmd()
def stats():
    global hp
    global hunger
    global gold
    print("HitPoints:",hp)
    print("Food:",hunger)
    print("Gold:",gold)
    cmd ()
def cmd():
    global location
    global hunger
    print()
    print(location.name)
    print()
    print(location.desc)
    print()
    hunger = hunger - 1
    urcmd = input("> ")
    if urcmd in northh:
        north()
    elif urcmd in inventory:
        if not inv:
            print("Inventory empty.")
        else:
            print(*inv,sep='\n')
        cmd()
    elif urcmd in eats:
        eat()
    elif urcmd in statss:
        stats()
    elif urcmd in attack:
        combat()
    elif urcmd in use:
        use()
    elif urcmd == ("exit"):
        print("Are you sure you want to quit?")
        print()
        print("All progress will be lost!")
        print()
        print("Y/N")
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans in yes:
            print("Ok, exiting...")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Ok, returning to game.")
            cmd()
    else:
        print("That is not a command. For a list of commands, type help.")
        cmd()
cmd()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ambitious first project! Actually coding is the best way to learn and SO is the best place to ask questions. I hope you are not discouraged by the downvotes, that happens when you post big blocks of code with "simple" mistakes in them. I know it's hard but in the future try to narrow your error down to a specific line and write the smallest program you can to reproduce the error (often you understand the problem yourself while doing this) and post any stack traces/error messages exactly the way you got them - it helps a lot. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: thank you all for the quick response time. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you go north the first time, your current position is set to the string `"CaveEntrance"` and not the `CaveEntrance` object.

Change this line:

```
Beach = Room("Beach", "The beach. The sand is warm and the water is inviting.",
             "Lantern", "CaveEntrance")
```

To:

```
Beach = Room("Beach", "The beach. The sand is warm and the water is inviting.",
             "Lantern", CaveEntrance)
```

Comment: This is indeed the quickest fix for the OP's current problem. The question he should ask himself now is, how is he going to implement a `south` attribute the same way? He won't be able to do `CaveEntrance = Room("CaveEntrance", "The entrance to a large cave.", "Lantern", Beach, None)`, since `Beach` doesn't exist yet. And he can't just move `Beach =` one line up, because then `CaveEntrance` won't exist yet.

Comment: Yes there is obviously `Room` for improvement in the game but since it is clearly a work in progress (you can only go north) and a "first project" it felt a bit out of scope so I wanted to focus on the bug itself. OP seems smart enough to figure the rest out by themselves. :)

Comment: You are correct. My room class system won't work, so I'll be using dictionaries.